# react axios post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an error while calling Axios, in React through handle click button and I have created an onlick function. I am getting errors on the last closing bracket.
the errors shows
Line 24:2:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (24:2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeGxp.png)
as a beginner i can't understand what is the problem
please look at the code and tell me what is the problem with **handleProducts**  function

```
const NewProduct = (props) => {
  const [carCompany, setcarCompany] = React.useState([]);
  const [carName, setcarName] = React.useState([]);
  const [carModel, setcarModel] = React.useState([]);
  const [carPrice, setcarPrice] = React.useState([]);
  const [Features, setFeatures] = React.useState([]);
  const handleProducts = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/products/create", {
        carCompany,
        carName,
        carModel,
        carPrice,
        Features,
      }
        .then(res=>{console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  };
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <h1>Enter Car details for Sale</h1>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>

      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          fullWidth
          label="Car Company"
          variant="filled"
          value={carCompany}
          onChange={(e) => setcarCompany(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          fullWidth
          label="Car Name"
          variant="filled"
          value={carName}
          onChange={(e) => setcarName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          fullWidth
          label="Model"
          variant="filled"
          value={carModel}
          onChange={(e) => setcarModel(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          fullWidth
          label="Price"
          variant="filled"
          value={carPrice}
          onChange={(e) => setcarPrice(e.target.value)}
        />

        <TextField
          id="filled-basic"
          fullWidth
          label="Features"
          variant="filled"
          value={Features}
          onChange={(e) => setFeatures(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <Button color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={handleProducts}>
          Add Details
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
        {carCompany}
        {carName}
        {carModel}
        {carPrice}
        {Features}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default NewProduct;
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: this is the error C:\Users\aamish\Desktop\react\react_crud\crud_system\src\components\NewProduct.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (24:2)

  22 |   .catch(error => {
  23 |     console.error(error);
> 24 | });
     |   ^
  25 | };
  26 |   return (
  27 |     <Grid container spacing={3}>

Comment: i have attached the image for your easiness

Comment: The first typo that stands out is you never closed the `.post()` function call (you're missing the closing parentheses).  There could be more such typos.  You should make consistent use of whitespace and formatting so you can more easily observe the structure of your own code and spot issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a bracket that should close the `post` method call. I suggest you use consistent indentation so you can see this more clearly in the future. It is up to you how to indent the code - you can put the `function call`, `then` and `catch` in the same column, or you can organize it in any other way that is clearer for you.
Here's the fixed code for `handleProducts`:

```
const handleProducts = () => {
  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/products/create", {
    carCompany,
    carName,
    carModel,
    carPrice,
    Features, 
  }).then(res => { 
       console.log(res.data); 
  }).catch(error => { 
       console.error(error); 
  });
};
```